# ¿Cuál es el limite de espacio para un array en Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift3, array, arraylist

Un array de `Int` por ejemplo

```
var someInt: [Int] = [1, 2, 3];
```

En teoria ¿Hasta que numero puede llegar? ¿O cuál es su capacidad?

Comment: Me parece que la longitud máxima sería el valor máximo de `Int`, solo leyendo las fuentes de `Array`

Comment: A mi me parece que tu pregunta va mas relacionado al __espacio de un Array__ que al __espacio de un elemento del Array__.

Comment: @Wilson Así es, yo pregunto cuál es su capacidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array) en la seccion **Growing the Size of an Array** dice asi:

> Cada Array reserva un especifico espacio de memoria para almacenar su
>   contenido. Cuando agregas elementos a un Array y este empieza a
>   exceder su capacidad reservada, el Array crea mas espacio de memoria
>   mas amplio y luego copia sus elementos a este nuevo almacenamiento.

En otras palabras, no tiene limite, a medida que el Array ve que podria quedarse sin espacio, reserva mas espacio y se traslada a este nuevo lugar.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de la arquitectura en que la estés ejecutando. En dispositivos de `32 bits`, tienes un máximo de `2^32` y en el caso de `64 bits` tienes `2^64` todo esto hablando en teoría. En la práctica, recuerda que hay limitaciones de memoria, CPU, etc ya que no es lo mismo almacenar un `Int` que un `Float` o un objeto.